# How to concat Pandas series and DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas

I would like to concat the Pandas Series into my Dataframe. My code works fine with Pandas append function, however, it seems that append will not be used in the future and I am not able to figure out how to solve it with pd.concat.

> Deprecated since version 1.4.0: Use concat() instead. For further
> details see Deprecated DataFrame.append and Series.append

Here is my code snippet:

```
>>> history_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Download_date', 'Name', 'Status'])
>>> history_dataframe
Out:
Download_date Name Status

>>> save_series = pd.Series([str(datetime.datetime.now())[:-7], file, 
                            'complete'])
>>> save_series
Out:
0  2022-05-02 10:37:28
1  testfile.txt
2  complete

>>> history_dataframe = pd.concat([history_dataframe,
                                  save_series], ignore_index =True)
>>> history_dataframe
Out:
   Download_date Name Status
 0           Nan  NaN    Nan 2022-05-02 10:37:27
 1           Nan  NaN    Nan testfile.txt
 2           Nan  NaN    Nan Complete
```

With `index = history_dataframe.columns` inside `pd.Series`, it shows `ValueError: Length of values (3) does not match length of index (4)`.

Any suggestions? Thx

Comment: why did you want to use `append` in the first place? Are you going to do this once or repeatedly?

Comment: @mozway Repeatedly ;-)

Comment: @LukášTůma - added solution for it.

Comment: @Lukáš the the best is likely NOT to concat repeatedly, but rather to collect the data and concat in the end, else you will run in quadratic complexity. I provided an example

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There are 3 values in Series, so index has list with `['Download_date', 'Name', 'Status']`:

```
save_series = pd.Series([str(datetime.datetime.now())[:-7],
                         file, 
                        'complete'], index=['Download_date', 'Name', 'Status'])
```

And then for `concat` create one row `DataFrame` by [`Series.to_frame`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_frame.html) and transpose:

```
history_dataframe = pd.concat([history_dataframe, save_series.to_frame().T], ignore_index =True)
```

Better is create list of Series and then only once pass to `DataFrame` constructor:

```
file = 'a.txt'
save_series = pd.Series([str(datetime.datetime.now())[:-7],
                             file, 
                            'complete'], index=['Download_date', 'Name', 'Status'])
    
print (save_series)

L = []
#sample loop
for i in range(3):
    L.append(save_series)


df = pd.DataFrame(L)
print (df)
         Download_date   Name    Status
0  2022-05-02 10:57:11  a.txt  complete
1  2022-05-02 10:57:11  a.txt  complete
2  2022-05-02 10:57:11  a.txt  complete
```

Answer (score 1):

You would need to convert your Series to DataFrame and transpose it, which is probably not really needed.

Why not just using loc in this case?

```
history_dataframe.loc[0] = save_series
```

output:

```
         Download_date          Name    Status
0  2022-05-02 10:51:08  testfile.txt  complete
```

input Series:

```
save_series = pd.Series([str(datetime.datetime.now())[:-7], file, 'complete'],
                        index=history_dataframe.columns)
```

##### many Series

Collect the data and concat in the end:

```
l = [save_series, save_series]  # create this in your loop or however you want
# then concat once
df = pd.concat(l, axis=1).T
```

example output:

```
         Download_date          Name    Status
0  2022-05-02 10:51:08  testfile.txt  complete
1  2022-05-02 10:51:08  testfile.txt  complete
```

Answer (score 0):

Basically if you create a `pandas Dataframe` it will create an index at the first column that's why you can't concatenate your `pandas series`.

Try recreating your `pandas Dataframe` and concatenate again.

```
history_dataframe = pd.DataFrame(columns=['Download_date', 'Name', 'Status'], ignore_index=True)
```